# How I do uninstall the apps old version after upgrading to a new version in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, storage

I am running Ubuntu Touch in my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu 14.10 (r19). I updated several applications.

Now, I have double applications: the old  and the new versions in my storage. By example: **System Configuration**/**About**/**Storage** is showing the updated applications in both versions. I need to remove the old version to free the storage space.

*ps: I don't know whether the apps are repeated really or whether is a bug of the storage widget.*

Comment: I improve my question with these notes:
1- The calculator application was updated.
2 - The apps scope shows the calculator icon once.
3- The storage widget (system/config/about this phone/storage) is showing two calculator icons: the previous version (1.3MB) and the updated version (1.8MB).

**Is it a bug in storage widget or the calculator applications are repeated really?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a official bug reported in this link:
[Storage shows same app multiple times (pre-installed and update from click store)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1265250)

The team is working in the solution.